# Why does With not inject value in some but not all places inside Manipulate arguments?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, evaluation

I was trying to create a `Manipulate` with a variable number of controls for the elements of an array.  Normally, you can inject the value of an iterator `i` with `With[{i = i},...]` into `Dynamic[..]`.  This works, but surprisingly, it does not inject the value into the instance of `i` outside the `Dynamic[]`.

```
With[{$maxterms = 4},
 Manipulate[
  a[[;; terms]],
  {{a, ConstantArray[0., $maxterms]}, None},
  {{terms, 2}, Range@$maxterms},
  Dynamic@ Column@ Table[
     With[{i = i},
      Control[{
        {a, ConstantArray[0., $maxterms], Subscript["a", i]},  (* i not injected *)
        0., 1, Manipulator[Dynamic[a[[i]]], ##2] &}]           (* i is injected *)
      ],
     {i, terms}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Using a fixed number of controls works:

```
With[{$maxterms = 4},
 Manipulate[
  < same three lines >,
  Evaluate@ Column@ Table[
     < same With[] code >,
     {i, $maxterms}]
  ]]
 ]
```

[image]

Apparently, the difference is `Dynamic@...` vs. `Evaluate@...`.  The second code does not work if `Evaluate` is omitted.

**Question:**
As a workaround, one can dynamically select from the `Table[]` in the second method, but why does the `Dynamic` construction in the first case fail?

Comment: For the first scenario, writing instead `Dynamic@Subscript["a", i]` makes the injection. Could it be that without this `Dynamic`, `Manipulate` does not bother to inject? This seems to be the case when removing `Dynamic` from `Manipulator` and writing instead `Manipulator[a[[i]], ##2] &`.

Comment: @xavier Yes, that's a nicer workaround.  I'm not sure what `Manipulate[]` is doing yet. It must be rewriting the code in some way. I guess I'm wondering whether it's a bug or I'm breaking some rule.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a partial answer.

`Manipulate[]` is rewriting the code in a way that breaks `With[]`. If we look that the `InputForm` of the evaluated code, we see that the code for `Control[..]` has been tagged with the option `ControlPlacement -> 1`, which apparently marks it to replace the placeholder `` Manipulate`Place[1] ``.

> ```
> With[{$maxterms = 4},
>      Manipulate[
>       a[[;; terms]],
>       {{a, ConstantArray[0., $maxterms]}, None},
>       {{terms, 2}, Range@$maxterms},
>       Dynamic@ Column@ Table[
>          With[{i = i},
>           Control[{
>             {a, ConstantArray[0., $maxterms], Subscript["a", i]},  (* i not injected *)
>         0., 1, Manipulator[Dynamic[a[[i]]], ##2] &}]           (* i is injected *)
>       ],
>      {i, terms}]
>   ]
>  ] // InputForm
> ```
>
> Input form:
>
> ```
> Manipulate[
>  a[[1 ;; terms]],
>   {{a, {0., 0., 0., 0.}}, 0, ControlType -> None},
>   {{terms, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4}},
>   {{a, {0., 0., 0., 0.}, Subscript["a", i$]}, 0., 1, 
>    Dynamic[Manipulator[Dynamic[a[[i$]]], ##2] & ],
>    ControlPlacement -> 1},
>   Dynamic[Column[
>    Table[With[{i$ = i}, Manipulate`Place[1]], {i, terms}]]]
>  ]
> ```

---

What is still unclear is how `` With[{i$ = i}, Manipulate`Place[1]] `` results in the symbol `i$` being replaced by the value of `i`.  It seems to have something to do with being wrapped in `Dynamic[]`.

For instance, if we add a `Dynamic@` to `Subscript["a", i]` in the following two ways, only the first of the two works:

```
Dynamic@Subscript["a", i]  (* WORKS (@xavier's workaround) *)
Subscript["a", Dynamic@i]  (* does NOT work *)
```

[image]

However, both codes work if we use a replacement rule instead of `With` to inject the value of `i`; just replace the original `Control[..]` code inside `Table[]` with this:

```
Control[{{a, ConstantArray[0., $maxterms],
      Subscript["a", Dynamic@i]    (* or replace with  Dynamic@Subscript["a", i]  *)
    },
    0., 1, Manipulator[Dynamic[a[[i]]], ##2] &}] /. HoldPattern[i] -> i
```

But the replacement rule method fails just like `With` in the OP if the control label is just `Subscript["a", i]`, not being wrapped by `Dynamic[]`.

---

Going back to the input form of the original code, I would expect `` Manipulate`Place[1] `` might be replaced by the control.  Something like this:

```
DynamicModule[{terms = 2, a = {0., 0., 0., 0.}}, 
 Dynamic[Column[Table[With[{i$ = i}, Manipulate`Place[1]], {i, terms}]]] /. 
  Manipulate`Place[1] ->
     Control@{{a, {0., 0., 0., 0.}, Subscript["a", i$]}, 
      0., 1, Dynamic[Manipulator[Dynamic[a[[i$]]], ##2] &], ControlPlacement -> 1}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But as can be seen, that actually works, so something else must be happening.