# How do I use a Do loop on a Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, scoping

How do I use Table or Do Loop iterators inside Manipulate? Is there a way to use Iterators inside a Manipulate function?

```
 Do[
  ToExpression[
    "CombinedCartesianPlot\[NumberSign]" <> ToString[Mass] <> 
   "\[NumberSign]" <> ToString[Radius], StandardForm,
    Function[sym, 
     sym = Manipulate[Show[
      {If[a == 1, 
        ToExpression[ 
         "CartesianPlotWith\[NumberSign]" <> ToString[Mass] <> 
          "\[NumberSign]" <> ToString[Radius]], Nothing], 
       If[a == 1, 
        ToExpression[
         "CartesianPlotWithout\[NumberSign]" <> ToString[Mass] <> 
          "\[NumberSign]" <> ToString[Radius]], Nothing]},   
      PlotLabel -> 
           
       "Positions of With and Without Photophoresis of a particle \
with #InsertRadiusHere#", 
      Frame -> True], {{a, 1, "With"}, {1, 0}}, {{b, 1, 
       "Without"}, {1, 0}}, ControlPlacement -> Top, 
     FrameMargins -> 0, TrackedSymbols :> {a, b}], 
      HoldAll]
    ],
  {Mass, 1, 6}, {Radius, 1, 6}
  ]
```

The Do Loop Iterators (Mass & Radius) would not be evaluated and are labeled Red instead.

Comment: Crossposted Here: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2468008

Comment: Your problem is about scoping of variables. I do not have an answer, but a work-around: Define ``manip[Mass_, Radius_] := Manipulate[...];`` and then use ``Do[manip[Mass, Radius], {Mass, 1, 6}, {Radius, 1, 6}]``.

Comment: I do not understand your code. Making a string and then changing it to an expression seems odd. If you explain your problem, we may better be able to help you.

Comment: A common way to inject values into held expressions, found in the docs for `Table` as well as [Introduction to Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html) and the [advanced one](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html) (search for `With[`), is `Do[With[{Mass = Mass, Radius = Radius}, ...rest of body...],  {Mass, 1, 6}, {Radius, 1, 6}]`, if that is what you're trying to do. (I recommend reading all four `Dynamic`/`Manipulate` tutorials, should you run into a problem with `Manipulate`, which above you have.)

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16893/4999. Odd related problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129380/4999

Comment: Can you explain what you are attempting to do?  All the `ToExpression` calls makes this feel like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).